# Is it possible to lock the layers using Qgis API Python?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I would need to load and "lock" two layers on the map. Locked means that layers cannot be removed from the layer registry. When I say removed I mean removed by the user using the QGIS interface (the remove button). And possibly make them as read only? Only if this would not interfere with the plug-in I am making, which manages and edit layer geometries, through customized GUIs I made.